# TEditor not working in android

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, rich-text-editor

I am implementing TEditor in a project in xamarin forms.There are no errors in code and building successfully.It is working fine in Simulator.But in real devices the data is not getting typed and also the styles are not working.

The project contains MasterDetailPage in Android.Can anyone of you please give me an idea to get my problem solved.

Or

Any one please suggest me another Plugin or Component or Package for the replacement of TEditor.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: By `not working`, can you show the errors?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Joe Lv.That is the release problem of the app.It is fixed now